# If Barry Allen took on the Flash name after Jay Garrick, what happened to the latter?

Tags: dc, the-flash

According to [ComicVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/flash/4015-56321/), Barry Allen named himself after Jay Garrick's Flash. Since they existed in the same universe, what happened to Jay Garrick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Jay Garrick was a comic character of Earth-2... not a real person on Barry Allen's Earth-1.

Per [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Jay_Garrick))

> In 1956, DC Comics reinvented the Flash character, giving him a new costume, name, and background. Named Barry Allen, he was completely unrelated to Jay Garrick. **In fact, Garrick never existed as far as the new books were concerned.** Barry Allen's first appearance shows him reading a copy of Flash Comics, lamenting Garrick was "just a character some writer dreamed up".

This is actually stated at the same ComicVine link:

> He [Barry Allen] also had a love of **comic books**, his favorite hero being the Flash ( Jay Garrick).

Eventually:

> In 1985, DC Comics merged all of its fictional characters into a single shared universe. Jay Garrick now shared the same world as the new Flash.

So, in answer to your question, they didn't actually exist in the ***same*** universe/Earth variant until much after Barry Allen's Flash was created.

You can read about the current "status" of Jay at the Wikepdia link.

Comment: >This is actually stated at the same ComicVine link                                 Thanks and apologies, I was aware of (and fooled by) the story (though haven't read it) "Flash of Two Worlds"